# React native firebase+webrtc for video call

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am unable to implement video call using RNFirebase.Whenever I click on call button.I get the below issue.
[image]

Error
[image]

Please find code for below files.

MainApplication.java

```
package com.videocall;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.videocall.generated.BasePackageList;

import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactAdapterPackage;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ModuleRegistryAdapter;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactModuleRegistryProvider;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.Package;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.SingletonModule;
import expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import com.twiliorn.library.TwilioPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.firestore.RNFirebaseFirestorePackage;


public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  private final ReactModuleRegistryProvider mModuleRegistryProvider = new ReactModuleRegistryProvider(
    new BasePackageList().getPackageList()
  );

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider));
      packages.add(new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage())
      packages.add(new RNFirebaseFirestorePackage());
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }

    @Override
    protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
      return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage();
    }

    @Override
    protected @Nullable String getJSBundleFile() {
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        return super.getJSBundleFile();
      } else {
        return UpdatesController.getInstance().getLaunchAssetFile();
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected @Nullable String getBundleAssetName() {
      if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        return super.getBundleAssetName();
      } else {
        return UpdatesController.getInstance().getBundleAssetName();
      }
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      UpdatesController.initialize(this);
    }

    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }
  @Override
  protected List getPackages() {
    @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
    List packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
    //  add the following code
    //packages.add(new TwilioPackage());
    
    return packages;
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.videocall.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

}

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useRef,useEffect } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";

import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Button from "./components/Button";
import GettingCall from "./components/GettingCall";
import Video from "./components/Video";
import {
  EventOnAddStream,
  MediaStream,
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCSessionDescriptionType,
} from "react-native-webrtc";
import Utils from "./Utils";
import firestore, {
  FirebaseFirestoreTypes,
} from "@react-native-firebase/firestore";

const configuration = { iceServers: [{ url: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }] };

export default function App() {
  const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState<MediaStream | null>();
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState<MediaStream | null>();
  const [gettingCall, setGettingCall] = useState(false);
  const pc = useRef<RTCPeerConnection>();
  const connecting = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const cRef = firestore().collection("meet").doc("chatId");
    const subscribe = cRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.data();

      //On answer start the call
      if (pc.current && !pc.current.remoteDescription && data && data.answer) {
        pc.current.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data.answer));
      }
      //if there is offer for chatId set the getting call flag
      if (data && data.offer && !connecting.current) {
        setGettingCall(true);
      }
    });

    //On delete of collection call hangup
    //The other side has  clicked on hangup
    const subscribeDelete = cRef.collection("callee").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type == "removed") {
          hangup();
        }
      });
    });
    return () => {
      subscribe()
      subscribeDelete()
    }
  }, []);

  const setupWebrtc = async () => {
    try {
      pc.current = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
      //Get the audio and video stream for the call
      const stream = await Utils.getStream();
      if (stream) {
        setLocalStream(stream);
        pc.current.addStream(stream);
      }
      //Get teh remote stream once it is available
      pc.current.onaddstream = (event: EventOnAddStream) => {
        setRemoteStream(event.stream);
      };
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    }
  };

  const create = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Calling");
      connecting.current = true;

      //setUp webrtc

      await setupWebrtc();

      //Document for the call
      const cRef = firestore().collection("meet").doc("chatId");

      //Exchange the ICE candidates between the caller and callee
      collectIceCandidates(cRef, "caller", "callee");
      if (pc.current) {
        //Create offer for the call
        //Store the offer under the document
        const offer = await pc.current.createOffer();
        pc.current.setLocalDescription(offer);

        const cWithOffer = {
          offer: {
            type: offer.type,
            sdp: offer.sdp,
          },
        };
        cRef.set(cWithOffer);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    }
  };

  const join = async () => {
    console.log("Joining the call");
    connecting.current = true;
    setGettingCall(false);

    const cRef = firestore().collection("meet").doc("chatId");
    const offer = await (await cRef.get()).data()?.offer;
    if (offer) {
      //setup webstrc
      await setupWebrtc();
      //Exchange the ICE candidates
      //Check the parameters.Its reversed.Since the joining part is callee
      collectIceCandidates(cRef, "callee", "caller");
      if (pc.current) {
        pc.current.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));
        //Create the answer for the call
        //Update the document with answer
        const answer = await pc.current.createAnswer();
        pc.current.setLocalDescription(answer);
        const cWithAnswer = {
          answer: {
            type: answer.type,
            sdp: answer.sdp,
          },
        };
        cRef.update(cWithAnswer);
      }
    }
  };

  /*
   * For disconnecting the call,close the connection,release the stream.
   * Delete the document for the call
   */

  const hangup = async () => {
    setGettingCall(false);
    connecting.current = false;
    streamCleanUp();
    firestoreCleanUp();
    if (pc.current) {
      pc.current.close();
    }
  };

  //Helper function

  const streamCleanUp = async () => {
    if (localStream) {
      localStream.getTracks().forEach((t) => t.stop());
      localStream.release();
    }
    setLocalStream(null);
    setRemoteStream(null);
  };
  const firestoreCleanUp = async () => {
    const cRef = firestore().collection("meet").doc("chatId");
    if (cRef) {
      const calleeCandidate = await cRef.collection("callee").get();
      calleeCandidate.forEach(async (candidate) => {
        await candidate.ref.delete();
      });
      const callerCandidate = await cRef.collection("caller").get();
      callerCandidate.forEach(async (candidate) => {
        await candidate.ref.delete();
      });
      cRef.delete();
    }
  };

  const collectIceCandidates = async (
    cRef: FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentReference<FirebaseFirestoreTypes.DocumentData>,
    localName: string,
    remoteName: string
  ) => {
    const candidateCollection = cRef.collection(localName);
    if (pc.current) {
      //On new ICE candidate add it to firestore
      pc.current.onicecandidate = (event) => {
        if (event.candidate) {
          candidateCollection.add(event.candidate);
        }
      };
    }
    //Get the ICE candidate added to firestore and update the local PC
    cRef.collection(remoteName).onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change: any) => {
        if (change.type == "added") {
          const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(change.doc.data());
          pc.current?.addIceCandidate(candidate);
        }
      });
    });
  };

  //Displays the getting call component
  if (gettingCall) {
    return <GettingCall hangup={hangup} join={join} />;
  }
  //Displays local stream on calling
  //Displays both local and remote stream once call is connected

  if (localStream) {
    return (
      <Video
        hangup={hangup}
        localStream={localStream}
        remoteStream={remoteStream}
      />
    );
  }
  //Displays the call button

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* <Button iconName='video'backgroundColor='grey'></Button> */}

      <Button iconName="video" backgroundColor="grey" onPress={create} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

android>build.gradle

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

android>app>build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: (findProperty('expo.jsEngine') ?: "jsc") == "hermes",
]

apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/expo-constants/scripts/get-app-config-android.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/create-manifest-android.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.videocall"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true 
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-twilio-video-webrtc')
    implementation project(path: ":@react-native-firebase_app")
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:{{ android.firebase.firestore }}"
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }
    addUnimodulesDependencies()

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.videocall">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <!-- OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS, REMOVE WHATEVER YOU DO NOT NEED -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <!-- These require runtime permissions on M -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <!-- END OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS -->
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="YOUR-APP-URL-HERE"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="YOUR-APP-SDK-VERSION-HERE"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Please advise on how to proceed.I have also google-services.json in android>app root folder

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment is getting deleted for some reason. Please check if you have placed the google-service.json in the correct place. The naming of that is file important. Make sure there is no number added at the end. It should be as you downloaded.

Comment: No there are no numbers added.

Comment: What is your expo version.

Comment: "expo": "~42.0.1", it is

Comment: Expo cli. Try updating it for the latest version. And creating the project again.